# razor div skips out with css ::after

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

This is my MVC partial view ,

```html
  <p class="contain mutliOptions method" id="paymentOptions">                                       
      @Html.Partial(MVC.Payment.Views._PaymentMethods, Model)
  </p>
```

When it renders the items in the view renders outside the p tag like below,

[image]

Why is the highlighted div skipping outside the div , any idea ?

Comment: why you have divs inside a `p`

Comment: It's impossible to have a div in a p. The browser simply closes the p before starting the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually originated from `<p>` tag is a block-level element which enables "tag omission", which automatically omit the closing tag and closes itself if these elements mentioned below are found before matching end tag `</p>`:

- `<address>`
- `<article>`
- `<aside>`
- `<blockquote>`
- ***`<div>`***
- `<dl>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<footer>`
- `<form>`
- `<h1>` to `<h6>`
- `<header>`
- `<hr>`
- `<menu>`
- `<nav>`
- `<ol>`
- `<pre>`
- `<section>`
- `<table>`
- `<ul>`
- another `<p>` element

Therefore, it implies that those block elements above cannot be nested inside `<p>` element.

Rather than using paragraph tag to nest other elements mentioned above, you can just use `<div>` tag for nested `<div>`s:

```
<div class="contain mutliOptions method" id="paymentOptions">                                       
    @Html.Partial(MVC.Payment.Views._PaymentMethods, Model)
</div>
```

Reference:

[The HTML paragraph element (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

Comment: I have already corrected this but your explanation deserves +1

Answer (score -1):

Just add following given div after your partial helper. hope it will work.

```
<p class="contain mutliOptions method" id="paymentOptions">                                       
      @Html.Partial(MVC.Payment.Views._PaymentMethods, Model)
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: No. It's impossible to have a div in a p. The browser simply closes the p before starting the div. Just test it if you doubt my word.